# Can I use an MVC 5 database for an ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm rewriting a relatively simple C# MVC 5 application to ASP.NET Core. I need to use the same data in this database. Is it possible to use the same database and simply connect to it with EF Core? Or do I need to create a complete new database and migrate the data to this new database?

Comment: It is possible, why shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can. Official documentation covers everything you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, not an ORM. It *doesn't* connect to any database. Your code uses ORMs like EF Core, libraries like Dapper or ADO.NET directly to connect to databases

Comment: If the question is `can I use EF Core with an existing database?` the answer is definitely yes. It would be useless otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same database for *any* language, framework, ..., as long as the language supports the connection to that DBMS.

A DB shouldn't be aware of how are built the applications that use it. Its goal is to store datas. You don't want to clone the same DB for differents applications, this may end up by having differents datas between each applications.

In example :

```
                             [Mobile application written in swift]
                                                |
                                                |
                                                |
                                                |
                                                V
[Web application written in php] ----------- > [DB] < ----------- [Fat client written in C#]
                                                ^
                                                |
                                                |
                                                |
                                                |
                       [Alien spaceship embedded software written in klingon]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that by `Creating a Model for an Existing Database` in Entity Framework Core
Use Scaffold-DbContext to create a model based on your existing database. The following parameters can be specified with `Scaffold-DbContext in Package Manager` Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext [-Connection] [-Provider] [-OutputDir] [-Context] [-Schemas>] [-Tables>] 
                    [-DataAnnotations] [-Force] [-Project] [-StartupProject] [<CommonParameters>]
```

In Visual Studio, `select menu Tools -> NuGet Package Manger -> Package Manger Console` and run the following command:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

[Oficial Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db) or

[Getting-Started-with-Entity-Framework-Core-Database First Development](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1209903/Getting-Started-with-Entity-Framework-Core-Databas)

Comment: Thanks, the obvious problem are the identity tables. Which i was hoping  I could use too. This seems harder and i'm thinking i just have to create new ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use EF6 with ASP.NET Core. "The recommended way to use Entity Framework 6 in an ASP.NET Core application is to put the EF6 context and model classes in a class library project that targets the full framework. ". 
Here is the documentation with a code sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.1 
 
Also, Microsoft does not recommend porting from EF6 to EF Core "unless you have a compelling reason to make the change". In case you want to do so, please read the documentation and make sure you validate the requirements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/